# Write a recursive function that copies some characters from start of each word in the parameter list to create a new string

Tags: python

I want to write a function using **recursion** that copies the first character from the first word in the list, 2 characters from second word and so on.

Here is what I wrote:

```
def word(words_list, i):
    if len(words_list[i]) <= 1:
        return words_list[i]
    else:
        return words_list[i][0] + get_code(words_list[i][1:],i)
    i += 1

>>>print(word(["tigers", "zebras", "and", "lions"], 0))
tzeandlion # Expected
ti # received
```

How can I go about this? Any help pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your setting, an option might be:

```py
def word(words_list, i=0):
    if i >= len(words_list):
        return ''
    return words_list[i][:i+1] + word(words_list, i + 1)

print(word(["tigers", "zebras", "and", "lions"])) # tzeandlion
```

With a different parameterization:

```py
def word(words_list, length=1):
    if not words_list:
        return ''
    return words_list[0][:length] + word(words_list[1:], length + 1)
```

If you were not required to use recursion, the following might be simpler and perhaps faster:

```py
output = ''.join(word[:length] for length, word in enumerate(words_list, start=1))
```